# Number theory problem! Prove the following using the method that relies on “Universal Generalization”.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $n$ is the product of four consecutive integers then $n+1$ is a perfect square. Domain is all natural numbers

What I got so far:
Let $a$ be an element of natural numbers selected arbitrarily
$a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3) = n$
$a(a+3)(a+1)(a+2)= n$
$(a^2+3a)(a^2+3a+2)=n$

I am stuck after this and don't know where to go. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)+1 = (a^2+3a+2)(a^2+3a)+1 = (a^2+3a)^2+ 2(a^2+3a) + 1 = (a^2+3a+1)^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \  (\underbrace{\color{}{a^2\!+\!3a}}_{\Large\ x^{\phantom{c}}})(\underbrace{a^2\!+\!3a\!+\!2}_{\Large x\ +\ 2})+1\,=\,x^2\!+2x\!+\!1\,=\, (\cdots)^2$

Answer (score 0):

You can take $$n = x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$$ $$n+1 = x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) + 1 = x^4 +6x^3 +11x^2 + 6x +1 =$$ 
$$(x^4 + 9x^2 + 6x^3) + (2x^2 + 6x) + 1 =  (x^2 + 3x)^2 + 1 + 2(x^2+3x) = (x^2+3x+1)^2 $$

Since x is a natural number, n+1 is a perfect square of a natural number.